# Change cell background color based on text in another column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

What would the syntax be to conditionally format - if any cell in Column A contains a value that matches any value in Column B then display a blue background?

Looks like this would be done using Conditional Formatting under Format, where this custom formula works.

```
=OR(A1:A1000="Text Sample 1",A1:A1000="Text Sample 2")
```

Instead of listing a bunch of values in this formula, is there syntax that can represent values listed in another column (Column B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B$1:B))
```

[image: 0]

---

for exact finds use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, B$1:B)&"$")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks,  This seems to only work for your sample.  Change aa in column b to aaa and you'll see what I mean. Its not a true match.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Formula:

```
=QUERY(B:B," Select count(B) where B is not null and '"&A1&"' contains B label count(B) ''",0)
```

Apply to:

```
A1:A
```

- Queries Column B for every cell in A  starting from A1 and outputs count of cells.